# 2005 Mercedes Benz CLK 500 key programing

Tags: key

I bought a 2005 Mercedes Benz CLK 500 with two keys but only one is programed to work with start/stop button.  Can the non working one be programed to work?

Comment: A simple search gave, and this could be a site for you... : http://www.slkworld.com/slk-r170-general-discussion/33461-can-you-re-program-key-fob.html#/topics/33461